# C++ program crashes on call to free()

Tags: c++, winapi, directory, 64-bit, free

I am writing a c++ program on Windows to recursively search a nested directory structure for a user-specified file(name). It successfully searches maybe thousands of subfolders (recursively, so depth-first), but not thousands-deep.

Eventually, it crashes on a call to `free()`, where I am freeing the local (to this recursive call of `searchDirectory()` function) arrays of file & directory names. Presumably I am mangling the heap somewhere?

My directory structure is many levels deep, but at the point of crash it is only 8 levels deep, and is at the point of returning up the call stack for a 2nd immediate time in a row when it crashes.

I have commented out most of my debugging `std::cout` lines, and you will see the calls to `free()` where it crashes are at the end of the `searchDirectory()` recursive function. I am using the win32 api and am compiling in 64-bit using the GNU C++ compiler. (NOTE: I have recompiled for 32bit and utilised gdb. This is the output:)

```
warning: HEAP[fn32.exe]:
warning: Heap block at 0B545728 modified at 0B5544B0 past requested size of ed80


Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x772bee8b in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

How is it that I am modifying memory outside of range?? As you can see from my code, I simply allocate using malloc(), use within the available range, then free()...

```
 #include <windows.h>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstring>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <algorithm>
 #include <iterator>
 #include <stdlib.h>

void seperateFilesFromFolders(WIN32_FIND_DATA[], WIN32_FIND_DATA [], WIN32_FIND_DATA  [], int *, int *);
void listFilesInDirectory(char[], WIN32_FIND_DATA[]);
void searchDirectory(char[]);

char filename[260] = { '\0' };

WIN32_FIND_DATA NullEntry;

char NullFileName[260] = { '\0' };

char backslash[] = "\\";
char star[] = "*";
char cd[] = ".";
char bd[] = "..";

unsigned int depth = 0;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc > 1)
        strcpy(filename, argv[1]);


    strcpy(NullEntry.cFileName, NullFileName);

    char localPath[] = ".\\";

    searchDirectory(localPath);

    std::cout << "COMPLETED.\n";

    return 0;
}

int cmp(char *a, char *b)   { // returns true (1) if the 2 c-strings match, as it should...

    if(strcmp(a, b)==0)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}


void searchDirectory(char path[])   {

    depth++;

    std::cout << "Entering searchDirectory(), path = " << path << std::endl;

    WIN32_FIND_DATA*  files = (WIN32_FIND_DATA*) calloc(400, sizeof(WIN32_FIND_DATA));
    WIN32_FIND_DATA* dirs = (WIN32_FIND_DATA*) calloc(190, sizeof(WIN32_FIND_DATA));

    if (files == NULL)  {

        std::cout << "FILES == NULL!" << std::endl;
    }
    if (dirs == NULL)   {

        std::cout << "DIRS == NULL!" << std::endl;
    }

    int di = 0;
    int fi = 0;

    char* localPath = (char*) calloc(260, sizeof(char));
    char* temp = (char*) calloc(260, sizeof(char));


    strcpy(localPath, path);

    strcpy(temp, localPath);
    strcat(temp, star);

    WIN32_FIND_DATA* entries = (WIN32_FIND_DATA*) calloc(1000, sizeof(WIN32_FIND_DATA));

    listFilesInDirectory(temp, entries);

    seperateFilesFromFolders(entries, files, dirs, &di, &fi);

    for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++)   {

        if (cmp(files[i].cFileName,NullEntry.cFileName))    {
            //std::cout << "File count for this directory == " << i << std::endl;
            break;
        }

        if (cmp(filename, files[i].cFileName))
            std::cout << "File match found in '" << temp << "'!" << std::endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 190; i++)   {

        if (cmp(dirs[i].cFileName,NullEntry.cFileName)) {

            //std::cout << "dirs[" << i << "].cFileName is Null." << std::endl;
            break;  
        }
        if (!cmp(dirs[i].cFileName, cd) && !cmp(dirs[i].cFileName, bd)) { // REMEMBER: DON'T RECURSIVELY SEARCH . OR .. !!!!!

            //std::cout << "dirs[" << i << "].cFileName = " << dirs[i].cFileName << std::endl;
            char subdirectory[260] = { '\0' };
            char localPath2[260] = { '\0' };

            strcpy(subdirectory, dirs[i].cFileName);

            strcpy(localPath2, localPath);
            strcat(localPath2, subdirectory);
            strcat(localPath2, backslash);

            searchDirectory(localPath2); 
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Depth = " << depth << std::endl;
    free(files);
    free(dirs);

    std::cout << "Returning from searchDirectory()..." << std::endl << std::endl;
    depth--;
}

void listFilesInDirectory(char path[], WIN32_FIND_DATA entries[])   {

    WIN32_FIND_DATA data;
    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(path, &data);      // DIRECTORY
    int i = 0;

    if ( hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )    {

        do  {

            //std::cout << data.cFileName << std::endl;
            entries[i++] = data;
        }
        while (FindNextFile(hFind, &data));

        FindClose(hFind);
    }
    else    {

    }

    std::cout << "There are " << i << " files & directories in the current directory. (" << path << ")" << std::endl;

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {

        //std::cout << entries[j].cFileName << " ";
        if (entries[j].dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) {

            //std::cout << "DIRECTORY";
        }
        else    {

            //std::cout << "FILE";
        }

        //std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    entries[i] = NullEntry;
    //std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    return;
}

void seperateFilesFromFolders(WIN32_FIND_DATA entries[], WIN32_FIND_DATA  files[], WIN32_FIND_DATA  dirs[], int *di, int *fi)   {

    int i = 0;
    while(!cmp(entries[i].cFileName,NullEntry.cFileName))   {

        if (entries[i].dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            dirs[(*di)++] = entries[i];

        else
            files[(*fi)++] = entries[i];

        i++;
    }

    //std::cout << "Made it out!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I'm sure you know that `sizeof(char)` is 1?

Comment: Where is the number of elements 1000 coming from?

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: curiousguy I just picked an arbitrary number, I modified the code as I went (bad habit I know!), and just picked a large-enough number. Also, yes, I know the size is 1, but I have MCI, and I don't always think. DevNull - okay, I'm on it.

Comment: In terms of "minimum reproducible example", I can't miss out any code, and it's impractical to provide the directory structure being used (it's a download of my google backup & sync data/my important data - I have recently factory-reset my box). I don't know what to do, except someone could run it from the root of a very deep, many-branched directory structure, having compiled on Windows...  I am just adding the output I have gotten from gdb (I recompiled for 32bit)

Comment: You are allocating fixed size buffers but never check if you are about to overrun them. Basing on `C++` tag, you should use `vestor` and `string` classes which automaticaly manage used memory.

Comment: Could you provide a dump file?

Comment: There is literally no need for `new`, `malloc`, `calloc`, `delete`, and `free` in C++. Have C++ manage resources for you. Once you've let that happen, you've drastically reduced to opportunities to write beyond the bounds of allocated memory. After you're done with that, replace your use of ANSI encoding with Unicode.

Comment: Whar are those magic number you use with `calloc`, like 400, 190, 260, 1000 etc.? And why are you programming with C idioms if you're using C++??

Comment: @Jabberwocky Those numbers are arrived at simply to make sure my code allocates enough memory to traverse my test directory structure, with some folders having >300 files. I don't want to initially allocate too much, to minimize risk of running out of memory, or similar. 1000 is still a quantity because I have iteratively updated my code, and it just hasn't been updated to 400+190. The 260 is the max path length under win32. I am new to C++, and "if it ain't broke, don't fix it" - I am just acclimatizing myself gradually to the paradigm.

Comment: @LeeDavidO'Dea suggested reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming). And you really shouldn't program with C idioms. Use the features of C++ and make your life easier.

Comment: @IInspectable surely if my program uses a recursive function that recurses deeply, I will run out of stack space if each stack frame is holding arrays of up to hundreds of strings?? I use "malloc" (and "new" where sensible) so that memory is allocated on the heap. My first implementation used local stack-allocated arrays, and I couldn't get anywhere near through the folder hierarchy like I can now. How can I allocate on the heap without using malloc or new, therefore free and delete?? (Bearing in mind, I want my code to be as compiler-compatible as possible, because it's going on github....)

Comment: `std::vector` and `std::string` allocate on the free store (aka the heap). There is no sensible way to manually manage resources in C++.

Comment: Thanks IInspectable. It's pushed to the front of my study list. I have utilised gdb, and esablished calloc() was eventually returning 0x00, causing a segfault when a subroutine tried to dereference it, all because my heap had run out of memory, because I forgot to free a block of memory assigned to "entries" in the primary recursive function at the end of the function. It works now!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why it was crashing on a call to `free()` (I can take an educated guess), but I do know, after some gdb debugging, that in the primary `searchDirectory()` recursive function, I was allocating a sizable block of memory on the heap using `calloc()`, and then forgot to `free()` the allocation at the end of the function! I have rectified my mistake, and my code works fine for a directory structure of 8637 nested folders, some of which have hundreds of files or sub-directories. I don't know what it's upper limit is, but it's not likely to be reached regardless of the depth or width of a directory structure, except of course that, obeying `win32`, the maximum path length is 260 chars.

Problem solved. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Hi, if the solution did resolve the issue, please feel free to mark yourself to help other people with the same issue.